# can openMPI cause performance problems on dual Hexacore machine?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

My computer has 2 Intel® Xeon® Processor X5650 with 6 cores each and HT support. But when i run MPI code it wont get past 6x speedup.
Here are some current run-times:

- NP  1: 20 minutes
- NP  6: 4 minutes
- NP 12: 3.5 minutes

---

- NP 24: 3.1 minutes (full HT)

So until 6 started Processes it runs like planned. All cores are active and the runtime decrease is linear. *Same with OpenMP*.
Could this be due cache incoherence on the mashine?
I heard about it someday on a MPI conference.

Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Post code and affinity options used in mpirun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, but this is problem specific - some applications simply do not scale linearly with the number of cores and there are many causes for this (e..g insufficient thread/data level parallelism in your application). In fact, in my experience, you'd be hard pressed to find an application other than embarrassingly parallel applications (e.g. Monte Carol simulation?) that do scale perfectly with the number of cores. It's unlikely anyone will give you an accurate answer without profiling the application, since there are many possible causes for sub-linear scaling.

However, in your case, the most obvious issue may be caused by HyperThreading (HT). The most counter-intuitive result you show is that moving from 12 threads to 24 threads (i.e. when using hyperthreading at its maximum) results in almost no speedup. In some cases, HT does not lead to performance increase. This is typical when:

1. running applications which fully utilise the CPU's arithmetic units. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) for example.
2. when there is substantial I/O from main memory (for example) per thread (in other words if your application becomes *memory bound*).  You can use the [roofline  model](http://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/PAR/research/roofline/) to see if your application is memory or compute bound.

This is because ultimately HT works by sharing many of the execution units within a CPU core between threads running on that core. If, for example each core has one floating point unit, that is shared for all threads running on that core, you cannot perform more than one floating point operation per clock cycle, regardless of how many threads you use. To investigate if this is the cause, I would suggest to disable HT (as there may even be a performance overhead). There is typically a kernel boot option on Unix machines to disable HT.

Finally, another typical issue is that dual socket machines are usually (?) [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) machines. This means that accessing the same memory contents from different CPUs may take different time. So your implementation should be NUMA-aware.

Comment: it turned out that a part of the program was not numa aware. The other part scaled perfectly to 12 porcessors. thanks for the hint